# Convert couple of rows into single row based on Duplicate ID in sql server from single/same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am going to do some arthimetic calulation for particular Id with two different category code.

So i have the below two row as input,

[image]

I am expecting the below output as,

[image]

I am trying to do some self join but i am not luckly getting the desired output.

Can you pls help me out here?

Note: Only two row will come for particular ID (Two type of categories will come [A or C]).

Comment: Please post the query you tried.

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1:**

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
Pivot (MAX(value) for Category in ([A],[C])) as Value
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b22c0/3)**

**Output:**

---

```
  +-------------+-------+-------+
  | ID          | A     |C      |
  +-------------+-------+-------+
  | WD559606479 | 0.748 |2.088  |
  +-------------+-------+-------+
```

**Method 2:** *Dynamic Pivot*

**If you have one more column** in the input then

Try this

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.category) 
            FROM table1 c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @query ='SELECT id, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                SELECT id
                    , category
                    , value
                FROM table1
            ) x
            Pivot 
            (
                Max(value)
                For category In (' + @cols + ')
            ) P'       
Execute(@query)
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b22c0/12)**

**Output:**

---

```
  +-------------+-------+-------+
  | ID          | A     |C      |
  +-------------+-------+-------+
  | WD559606479 | 0.748 |2.088  |
  +-------------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the partial solution, but if we have one more column in the input then what we need to do?

Answer (score 2):

> Only two row will come for particular ID (Two type of categories will
>   come [A or C]).

Then this query should be sufficient:

```
SELECT ID,
       ValueA = SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'A' THEN Value END),
       ValueC = SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'C' THEN Value END)
FROM dbo.TableName
GROUP BY ID
```

[**Sql-Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/70d45/1/0)